# angular 2 multiple checkbox preselect

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a multiple checkbox list in my page.

```
<label class="each-topic each-hcp" for="hcp{{hcpinfo.id}}{{hcpinfo.firstName}}" *ngFor="let hcpinfo of hcplist; let i=index">
    <input type="checkbox" name="hcpid" id="hcp{{hcpinfo.id}}{{hcpinfo.firstName}}" value="{{hcpinfo.id}}">
    <h4>{{hcpinfo.firstName}}</h4>
</label>
```

In my .ts file I have a predefined array as `this.hcparr`.

This contains values like  [5,8,10] - as `array`.

If `hcparr` has `hcpinfo.id` value then the corresponding checkbox needs to be selected.

How do you implement the if condition with multiple check box with this array list?

Please help me.

Comment: try adding up a plunker to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `checked` binding:

```
 <label class="each-topic each-hcp"  *ngFor="let hcpinfo of hcplist; let i=index" >                
  <input type="checkbox" name="hcpid" id="hcp{{hcpinfo.id}}{{hcpinfo.firstName}}" value="{{hcpinfo.id}}" [checked]="hcparr.indexOf(hcpinfo.id) > -1" >
  <span>{{hcpinfo.firstName}}</span>          
 </label>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cofb3m?file=src/app/app.component.ts)